# Android app cannot run in the background

Tags: java, android

I click on the **"home"** button to run in the background app.A few hours later I open the app again,but it run the `OnCreate()` method.I tried to used the `android:alwaysRetainTaskState` attribute and  I saw it didn't change anything. So what should I do?

Comment: when you clicked home button activity was paused ie in background. It might have been destroyed to reclaim memory. Hence when you open again the activity is recreated.

Comment: uh, yes.How I should do it? I don't want to recreated the activity.Thanks

Comment: its the way it works. use a service which runs in background. activity is paused when in background. it does not run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activities cannot be run in background. There for we got [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Espacialy look at [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), but it also have it's limitations. There isn't any other way.

Comment: How do I save activity content when I reopened the activity? Thanks.

Comment: @soxfmr You should ask it in new question, there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to run any task in background use services as @Babibu said.
here is a link which may help u out.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html 
go through examples in it.